# Fluent Validation WithMessage not working correctly with a SetValidator

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have successfully used WithMessage in the following form:

```
RuleFor(p => p.MyField)
             .NotEmpty()                            
             .WithMessage("{0} is Required",
                                p => p.SomeOtherField
                            );
```

This allows the value of SomeOtherField to be used in the error message.

I have a more complex requirement, where I use SetValidator with my own custom PropertyValidator as follows:

What I thought would work was the following:

```
RuleFor(x => x.MyField)                
            .SetValidator(
                    new RemoteValidator(                            
                        "Validate", 
                        "Home", 
                        System.Web.Mvc.HttpVerbs.Post, 
                        "*.SomeOtherProperty1,*.SomeOtherProperty2")
            )
            .WithMessage("{0} is not valid",
                                p => p.MyOtherField
                            )
            ;
```

...but it does not. When the validation fails, I get the message:

> {0} is not valid

eg. the {0} is not replaced

Any ideas?

From [here](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising) I found the concept of PropertyNameResolver which sounds like it might fit, but I cannot figure out how to configure this. The example on that link gives:

```
ValidatorOptions.PropertyNameResolver = (type, member) => {
  if(member != null) {
     return member.Name + "Foo";
  }
  return null;
};
```

I'm using Fluent Validations v5.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually an issue with my custom Validator.

I am following [this pattern](http://nripendra-newa.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/fluent-validation-remote-validation.html) which makes it way more customised and is wrapping MVC's remote attribute.

replacing it with a more "normal" custom validator, and this bit works fine:

```
.WithMessage("{0} is not valid",
                            p => p.MyOtherField
                        )
        ;
```